# is find_by_id sql injection safe in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection

I have following code in my rails controller:

```
State.find_by_id(params[id])
```

here params[id] is a user input 
Do I need to sanitize this parameter to make the above call safe from SQL injection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this method is ActiveRecord::FinderMethods and it safe.

small example:

```
User.find_by_id("' OR 1 --")
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]

=> nil
```

Comment: For more reading, check out [this helpful post](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#injection) on the Rails' guide.

Answer (score 0):

`find_by` already sanitize params.

Answer (score 0):

`find_by_id` uses to_i, so no string can be use here.
`Person.find_by_id('any string')` will be the same as `Person.find_by_id(0)`.

> Find by id - This can either be a specific id (1), a list of ids (1, 5, 6), or an array of ids ([5, 6, 10]).
>        If no record can be found for all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised. If the primary key
>        is an integer, find by id coerces its arguments using +to_i+.

```
Person.find(1)          # returns the object for ID = 1
Person.find("1")        # returns the object for ID = 1
Person.find("31-sarah") # returns the object for ID = 31
Person.find(1, 2, 6)    # returns an array for objects with IDs in (1, 2, 6)
Person.find([7, 17])    # returns an array for objects with IDs in (7, 17)
Person.find([1])        # returns an array for the object with ID = 1
Person.where("administrator = 1").order("created_on DESC").find(1)
```